# @HostListener not working on iPad or IOS. I am using a bluetooth keyboard trying to control an angular app

Tags: ios, angular

I am trying to build a web app in angular 6 for 9.7 in iPad. I use this code similar to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-or7gwr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

"

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export enum KEY_CODE {
  RIGHT_ARROW = 39,
  LEFT_ARROW = 37
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  value = 0;
  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);

    if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.RIGHT_ARROW) {
      this.increment();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.LEFT_ARROW) {
      this.decrement();
    }
  }

  increment() {
    this.value++;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.value--;
  }
}
```

"

The code is from the website above.

This approach works on my computer but not on the iPad. How can I get it to work on my iPad? you can use the website above for a demo.

Did anyone figure out a way to do it? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Thanks that actually gave me some hints, I ended up using "keydown" and changed the keys to "WASD" instead of the arrows. iPad returns a 0 for arrows. Not sure what to use for the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

iPad for web applications on a "keydown" recognizes the letters, spacebars and escape keys (the only ones I tested). Try safari in develop mode which helps a ton. I switched from arrow keys to WASD keys to solve the problem. Still not sure how to get the arrows but this is a temporary fix.

just FYI, arrow keys fire a 0, when pressed on the iPad